# Picklist field populate based on Profile

Tags: formula, profile

I need to default a picklist field based on the Profile. Test would be populated if a record is created by this Profile 2F00e0R000001GPDN. And Test2 would be populated if this profile creates the record 2F00e1W000000jzjQ

```
IF(
    OR(
        $Profile.Id = '2F00e0R000001GPDN', 'Test'),
        ($Profile.Id = '2F00e1W000000jzjQ','Test2')
    )
)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also, as @DerekF showed in his edit, indenting Formulas and Validation Rules similar to how your would other code (e.g., Apex), makes it much easier to read & follow the logic - which makes it much easier to help find issues and/or errors when they arise.

Comment: Have you tried your code? If so, what error did you get, or what happened that you did not expect to happen?

Comment: I'm receiving an error Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Comment: See Derek's answer below for the reason why. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2):

Profile Ids change when they're deployed to other orgs, so I'd argue for using `$Profile.Name` instead of `$Profile.Id`

That aside, a few points:

#### Formula fields cannot set the value of other fields

You didn't specify *where* this formula was being used so, just to cover all the bases, if you're trying to make this a formula field, that is not the correct approach.

Instead, you'll want to use this formula as part of a before-save record triggered flow. This could also be accomplished with a workflow rule + field update action (which is the legacy way to do this), or using Process Builder (but please don't use Process Builder for this).

#### Your syntax for the `IF()` function is not correct

you should be getting an error when trying to save this formula

The `IF()` function takes 3 arguments

- The condition to evaluate
- The value to return if the condition evaluates to TRUE
- The value to return if the condition evaluates to FALSE

That `OR()` that you're currently using is not correct here. Keeping with the way that `IF()` behaves, you'd be looking for something like "If the profile is X, then return value A, else if the profile is Y, then return value B"

You'd nest one `IF()` function in another to achieve this

```
IF(
    $Profile.Name = 'Profile 1',
    'Test',
    IF(
        $Profile.Name = 'Profile 2',
        'Test 2',
        /* The IF() function must always have 3 arguments */
        ' A default value to use when the profile is neither Profile 1 or Profile 2'
    )
)
```

#### The way I'd recommend

Using `IF()` is fine, but can become very hard to read beyond 2-3 nested levels of it.

Using the `CASE()` function helps keep things on a single level (which is easier to read)

```
CASE( $Profile.Name,
    /* The first argument is always the thing you want to use for comparison */
    /* Every pair of arguments after that is <target value>, <result> */
    'Profile 1', 'Test',
    'Profile 2', 'Test 2,
    /* The final argument is the default value (when none of the target values are matched */,
    'My default value'
)
```

#### The first place you should check when having formula trouble

is the documentation

Aside from it being a pain to navigate in chrome-like browsers, the [documentation on Formula Operatiors and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=sf.customize_functions.htm) is pretty good about telling you how to use the different functions.

The documentation on the `IF()` function should have made it very clear that your usage was incorrect. Quoting from the documentation page

> #### Description:
>
> Determines if expressions are true or false. Returns a given
> value if true and another value if false.
>
> #### Use:
>
> IF(logical_test, value_if_true,
> value_if_false) and replace
> logical_test with the expression you want evaluated; replace
> value_if_true with the value you want returned if the
> expression is true; replace value_if_false with the value you
> want returned if the expression is false.